# using jqGrid ruins jquery-ui dialog overlay in IE8 ruins?

Tags: html, jqgrid, overlay, jquery-ui-dialog, ie8-compatibility-mode

I know there is similar problem in the website but I can't find a proper solution for this.

I am using a jquery-ui dialog to display modal form in IE10.

But things are not working when I switched to **Browswer Mode: IE8** + **Document Mode: IE8 Standard** and added the jquery.jqGrid.src.js to the html file (Even though i do not add a jqgrid to the html).

The problem : The dialog is behind its overlay. And that makes user unable to click anything on the dialog.

Below is my simplified code..

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head>
<script language='javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script language='javascript' src='jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script language='javascript' src='jquery.jqGrid.src.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen'     href='themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='ui.jqgrid.css' />
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='dialog-message'>
Dummy Message
</div>
Dummy Message
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove this line `<script language='javascript' src='jquery.jqGrid.src.js'></script>` the dialog shows perfectly. But in my project i need to use both jqGrid and jquery-ui dialog in the same page in IE-8.

I have  tried to view the DOM elements using IE10 developer tools (F12) and find that if I include jqGrid js , the overlay div somehow has been moved to the end (the order of dialog div and overlay is swapped) maybe that gives some hints.

There is no problem with IE9, IE10, IE7 settings though.

Please help. Thank you!

Alex

Comment: Import the css files first then import external javascript files. Let know what you have got.

Comment: Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TntEg/) here.

Comment: Thanks for reply but the fiddle doesn't work at all when switched to "Browser Mode: IE8" + "Document Mode: IE8 standards"

Comment: Yeah, It's strange. jsfiddle seems not working when switched to IE7&8. Try importing `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` file after css files. It may help you. Because some grid functions required css to be loaded earlier than js.

Comment: I have tried to reorder the statement and include css before the js. It does not fix anything in IE8 standard mode. Hopefully, I just found that the problem does not exist in a real IE8 - It only appears in certain combination of browser mode in IE10. It only appears if I select Browser mode: IE8 + Docomument Mode: IE8 Standard / IE9Standard combinations).